# How can I detect the user's country and modify the website to a country-specific version?

Tags: redirect, ip-geolocation, country

Can anyone tell me how to do that, just like when I surf google.com it directs me to google.co.uk. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called IP geolocation.  There are a great variety of services and libraries for this.  You can get more specifics if you tell us what platform you're on.

Comment: if i'm not wrong i've heard about it, but i think it's only support in browser which support html5?

Comment: No.  The server is what's sending the redirect (google.com->google.co.uk) header, and there's no HTML involved.  You're right that HTML 5 provides client-side geolocation.  However, it's used for other purposes, and often relies on Wi-Fi or GPS data, rather than just IP geolocation.

Comment: where can i get the api?Thanks!

Comment: @drama, as I said, tell us what platform (language, etc.) you're on.

Comment: In that case, check out [Is there any possible way to find the name of the country using IP with scripting language PHP ?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543437/is-there-any-possible-way-to-find-the-name-of-the-country-using-ip-with-scripting).